# is there anyway to write Arabic root in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I have searched in the internet about writing Arabic root in Libreoffice without any results ?!
Is there a way to write an Arabic root in Libreoffice or not ?

Thought: the complex text layout has to do nothing with the Arabic root or the Arabic math symbols.

Comment: Libreoffice still does not support RTL Math (Right-to-Left), you may look for http://www.wiris.com/solutions/arabic as workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Click on tools --> options

[image]

Once the options window open, click on language settings --> languages, and make sure that you have a check mark in Complex Text Layout, and choose Arabic.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: thank you brother, but this have to do nothing with the Arabic root, its not exist at the formula